# The pullback of an irreducible analytic hypersurface(as a codimension 1 analytic subvariety)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Trying to prove the following: Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism between complex manifolds. Suppose $Z$ is an analytic hypersurface of $Y$, and no component of $f(X)$ is contained in $Y$, then $f^{-1}(Z)$ is an analytic hypersurface.

What does it mean by saying that no component of $f(X)$ is contained in $Y$? The local defining functions of $f^{-1}(Z)$ is given by taking the locally defining functions for $Z$ and compose it with $f$. Now it remains to show there is at least one smooth point. How is that guaranteed to exist?

Source: This is taken from Daniel Huybrechts' complex geometry page 80. Also in his definition of analytic subvariety, he does not mention that we need the defining function to be nonzero. Is that necessary?

Comment: Without knowing the source, it can be tough to tell for sure - would you be able to add the source to your question? The point is probably something like this, though: if no component of $f(X)$ is contained in $Y$, then the pullback of the not-identically-zero analytic function cutting out $Z$ pulls back to a not-identically-zero analytic function on $X$ and therefore also determines a hypersurface.

Comment: An union of analytic hypersurfaces is such that for each $z\in Z$, there is some complex  neighborhood $z\in U\subset Y$ and some non-zero analytic function $h:U\to \Bbb{C}$ such that $Z\cap U = \{ u\in U, h(u)=0\}$. This condition translates easily to $f^{-1}(Z)$. From there it remains to assume that $Z$ is irreducible and to decompose $f^{-1}(Z)$ into an union of irreducible hypersurfaces.

Comment: I have added the source

Comment: @reuns Is the assumption that the defining function be nonzero necessary? Huybrecht's book does not mention that. Demaily's definition for analytic set does not have that condition as well.

Comment: The vanishing set of $0$ is the whole of $X$ it doesn't have codimension $1$. Analytic sets can have any (co)dimension, here we are dealing with hypersurfaces.

Comment: I see, but how does one guarantee that there is at least one point at which the deferential of the defining function has rank 1(a smooth/regular point)?

Comment: I think you mean no component of $f(X)$ is contained in $Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following material from page 77 should help clear things up:

> **Definition 2.3.1**: An *analytic hypersurface* of $X$ is an analytic subvariety of codimension one.
>
> A hypersurface $Y\subset X$ is locally given as the zero set of a non-trivial holomorphic function. Indeed, locally $Y\subset X$ induces germs of codimension one and any such germ is the zero set of a single (non-trivial) holomorphic function (cf. Remark 1.1.32).

This is verbatim from the text with the exception of the parenthetical (non-trivial) which I added.

Now to the text you have an issue with, on page 80:

> i) Let $f:X\to Y$ be a holomorphic map and let $Z\subset Y$ be an irreducible hypersurface such that no component of $f(X)$ is contained in $Z$. Then the preimage $f^{-1}(Z)$ of $Z$ is again a hypersurface, although in general not irreducible. Indeed, if $Z$ is locally the zero set of a holomorphic function $g$ then $f^{-1}(Z)$ is the zero set of $g\circ f$.

$X$, being a manifold, is a disjoint union of it's connected components $X_i$. We can ask whether any $X_i\subset Z$ as sets. If this is true, then any function $g$ which vanishes on $Z$ $Z$ pulls back to $0$ on $X_i$ (write down what pullback means). This is a problem: $g\circ f$ is then zero on $X_i$, which means that for any choice of $g$ locally cutting out $Z$, we have that $g\circ f(X_i)=0$, or $f^{-1}(Z)\cap X_i = X_i$, and $f^{-1}(Z)$ is no longer a hypersurface because it's not codimension one everywhere.

If we require that no component is contained in $Z$, then for any nontrivial holomorphic function $g$ defined on some open subset $U\subset Y$, we always have that $g\circ f$ is again a nontrivial holomorphic function on $f^{-1}(U)$. This means that it cuts out a hypersurface per the discussion from page 77.

To assuage your concerns about smoothness, the following text from page 63 is relevant:

> Analogously to Exercise 1.1.14 one shows that the set of regular points $Y_{reg}=Y\setminus Y_{sing}$ is a non-empty complex submanifold of $X$ (cf Exercise 2.6.4). ... The dimension of an irreducible analytic subvariety $Y\subset X$ is by definition $\dim(Y)=\dim(Y_{reg})$. A *hypersurface* is an analytic subvariety of codimension one.

This means that using Huybrecht's definitions, *any* complex subvariety is generically smooth - so smooth points are very abundant (they're dense, and in particular, they exist). This gives the requested smooth point you ask after.

(Using other definitions - if your complex subvariety is a set plus a sheaf of functions, for instance - it's possible for this to be false, and with these definitions the correct version of the statement is that a **reduced** complex subvariety is generically smooth. Compare to algebraic geometry.)

Comment: Isn't $z = 0$ just $\{0\}$? How could it be a hypersurface?

Comment: It's a hypersurface in $\Bbb C$: an analytic subvariety of complex codimension one. Since the ambient space has one complex dimension, that means it's a (collection of) point(s).

Comment: Right that is true. But in order to guarantee codimension 1(definition at page 63), wouldn't we want to ensure the existence of local defining functions whose derivative is nonzero? In your example $z^2$ has derivative zero at zero but $z^2 =  0$ can also be defined by $z = 0$ which has derivative $1$ at zero.

Comment: I've updated the answer - the explanation is further on in that same text. You're right that I did not see that, but given that the explanation is on the same page and you did not see it either, I would encourage you to read a little more too, especially since most of my answer is just quoting the textbook back to you :) (Please also include more details and specifics in your question next time - ideally questions will be accessible to those without the text in front of them.)

Comment: As for the example, it depends on what definitions you pick - if you talk in terms of locally ringed spaces, you can do this, but if you're only beholden to the set, then your explanation is valid and my example vanishes in to a puff of nilpotency.