# Well-definedness of pull-back of divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I read this paragraph from Complex Geometry by Huybrechts:

> ...The pull-back of a divisor $D$ under a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is not always well-defined, one has to assume that the image of $f$ is not contained in the support of $D$. Thus, one usually considers only dominant morphisms...

So why would the pull-back be not well-defined if the image of $f$ is contained in the support of $D$? And why does dominant morphisms solve this issue?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3560492/the-pullback-of-an-irreducible-analytic-hypersurfaceas-a-codimension-1-analytic/3569683#3569683), though in the algebraic world instead of the analytic one. Do you think the linked question solves your issues?

Comment: @KReiser Yes that one explains well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you are working with weil divisors on a regular variety. Then, effective divisor correspond to codimension 1 subvarieties. In this case, if the image of $f$ is contained in the support of $D$; then the pullack would be all of $X$, which is not a divisor.

Taking a dominant morphism solves the issue, because then the image of $f$ will be an open subset, and a codimension 1 subvariety of $Y$ cannot contain any open subset.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation. One very minor thing, though: it may not actually be the case that the image of $f$ is an open subset - take $\Bbb A^2\to \Bbb A^2$ by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,xy)$, for instance. Instead, one should say that the image of a dominant map is dense, and then your explanation is completely fine - no dense set is contained in a codimension one subvariety.